# Build a controller for an arm (no PR2)

Tags: ros, microcontroller, hardware, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i want to use ROS to work with a SSC32 card, but i can't find information about how to build a controller for it. I had readed about pr2_controller_interface, pr2_mechanims_model,  ( http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism_model), hardware_interface, joints, urdf, etc...
but i don't understood what interface do i must implement and how use it.

Where can i find instruccions about it, or somebody can give some advice?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9190/build-a-controller-for-an-arm-(no-pr2)/) by [charias98](https://answers.ros.org/users/140/charias98/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

We did it for our own interactive arm with three actuators that communicate through a CAN bus. Here's a quick rundown of what we built and what you might need:

- A valid URDF definition of your joints and actuators,
- A bridge class that will own instances of:
- A pr2::HardwareInterface
- A pr2::ControllerManager
- One pr2_hardware_interface::Actuator for each of your motors
- A node for hardware communication that will own the bridge class.

At initialization, your bridge class will create the actuators that should appear in your URDF and add them to the hardware interface. You will then create the controller manager and link it to the hardware interface. After loading your URDF XML into the controller manager (initXML(...)) you will be ready to periodically update your controller manager, which should call any other controllers you want to run, e.g. a JointSplineTrajectoryController.

I'm not familiar with SSC32 cards, but with our setup we communicate the state through each actuator instance that was added to the hardware interface. The controller manager update cycle will get these values automatically and propagate them to controllers. We run separate threads to get values to and from our bus, and call the controller manager update() method in its own thread.

Hope this helps,

---

Originally posted by [francoisferland](https://answers.ros.org/users/184/francoisferland/) with karma: 66 on 2011-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [francoisferland](https://answers.ros.org/users/184/francoisferland/) on 2011-02-27**:
We don't extend these classes, we used them as-is. As for communicating with the card, we have a second class that has a an instance of the bridge. It periodically updates the actuator values and read back the command_effort to send it to the actuators.

**Comment by [charias98](https://answers.ros.org/users/140/charias98/) on 2011-02-25**:
Thanks  a lot for your answer. It helps a lot, but I still have some questions: the instances of  ControllerManager and ACtuator that i must to put in my bridge class  there are objects of the original classes or must i extend them? Which class send the digital signals to card? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please note that our lab (Steven Bellens) wrote a driver for this card:

- [ros.org/wiki/SSC32](http://www.ros.org/wiki/SSC32)

You can find our code on our GIT server (it moved from SVN, but is also kept on our SVN):

- [Our GIT Server](http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/?p=robotics/ssc32_hardware.git;a=summary)

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-02-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After calling the update on the controller manager, we read back the commanded_effort variable and send it to our actuator drives. Look into the ethercat_hardware package or even pr2_gazebo_plugins and the gazebo_ros_controller_manager to see how they do it on the PR2. The later is a bit easier to follow, everything is done in the gazebo_ros_controller_manager.cpp file, from URDF parsing to sending commanded efforts.

Here we actually cheat a little bit on our setup. Since we already have microcontrollers with PID loops that accepts positions as commands for each of our actuators, we set the joint spline trajectory controller p and d parameters as {1,0} so the commanded_effort variable only contain the full joint position error.

---

Originally posted by [francoisferland](https://answers.ros.org/users/184/francoisferland/) with karma: 66 on 2011-02-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Cool, thanks! I was looking into the ethercat nodes before, but didn't really find the point where the data is actually transmitted to the mcu boards. Anyway, will check the Gazebo nodes.
Interesting point what you said about sending the full joint position error. I thought in case of PR2 motor control would be outsourced to mcu level as well. But come to think of it, it is more flexible to keep the actual control centralized within the control computer to be more flexible when it comes to trying new controlers etc.

---

Originally posted by [Klaus](https://answers.ros.org/users/202/klaus/) with karma: 11 on 2011-02-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [francoisferland](https://answers.ros.org/users/184/francoisferland/) on 2011-02-27**:
Yep, that's exactly what we do. If I understand it correctly, on the PR2 they run all their controllers on a realtime kernel. They also use special publishers and subscribers for internal communication to limit message copying and stay realtime. It's somewhat similar to the nodelets API.

**Comment by [Klaus](https://answers.ros.org/users/202/klaus/) on 2011-02-27**:
Ah ok, now I see the point: I need to create a kind of container thread that runs the controller manager and manages the communication with my hardware. Then I need to copy the transmitted actuator commands (from the controller) into commands for my hardware manually within the container thread. Took me a while to realize that. Might be nice to have some kind of overview diagram for that in the documentation.